# How Hibernate Decide default length and datatype for columns of table while using Auto DDL

Tags: hibernate

1. When we are using hbm2ddl.auto with any POJO class then what is the rule that hibernate use to decide datatype and length of column fields?
2. How to provide custom data type and length for each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @length and @type annotation for custom length and datatype for the column.

```
@Type(type="text")
private String payable_amount;
```

Here return type is String the value which get stored in database will be in varChar format.

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDateTime")
```

Here is an example for LocalDateTime form from PersistentLocalDateTime
If we use customised class object as the type then the full class path has to be mentioned in the @type annotation.

Similarly length can be added to the column.By using it we can use max or min column length. Length annotation can only be used for Strings.

```
@Column(name = "NAME",length = 50)  
@Length(max = 50)
public String getName() {
  return this.name;
}
```